# Web scraping Google Scholar with Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hi I need to extract abstracts e DOI taken from records in Google Scholar, using bs4 or Selenium. I have a problem with pages of "academic.oup" like this:
https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article-abstract/42/Supplement_1/ehab724.1650/6394300

I'm not able to extract neither DOI nor abstract with bs4 or selenium.
Here is my code with selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/cante/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article-abstract/42/Supplement_1/ehab724.1650/6394300')
abstract = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentTab"]/div[1]/div/div/section')
doi_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentColumn"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/a')

for element in abstract:
    print(x, element.text)
for element in doi_element:
    print(x, element.text)

driver.quit()
```

And my result is empty (I found the XPath from the link of the page).
Here is my code with bs4:

```
response = requests.get('https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article-abstract/42/Supplement_1/ehab724.1650/6394300', headers=headers)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status code:', response.status_code)
    raise Exception('Failed to fetch web page ')

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for entry in page.find_all("seciton", attrs={"class": "abstract"}):
    print(entry.get_text())
```

And my result is also empty.
What is the problem?

Comment: Try to set headers on `requests`. `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0'}`
Also, it would be better to use `response.raise_for_status()`. One more thing. Its `section` not `seciton`

Comment: You have a single element for the abstract,doi_element which can be used by displaying it's .get_attribute('innerHMTL') and so forth.

Comment: Thank you maybe the problem was the headers. But how can I know what are the right headers to use with the requests function?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `beautifulsoup` for this than `selenium`.

As AlexDotis has mentioned in the comments, use `headers` in your GET request to get a successful response i.e, `200 Response`. Without which you get a `404 Response`.

This code will print the **Abstract**. *I am not sure what do you mean by **DOI** so I left it for you*.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article/42/Supplement_1/ehab724.1650/6394300'
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

s = soup.find('section', class_='abstract')

divs = s.find_all('div', class_='sec')
for div in d:
    title = div.find('div', class_='title').text.strip()
    tex = None
    p_tex = div.find('p')
    if p_tex:
        tex = p_tex.text.strip()
    print(f'\n{title}\n{tex}\n')
```